# Is it possible to store data in Raspberry Pi?

Tags: memory

I'm sorry if my question is very basic for some of you.

I'm developping an application which is becoming complex. Currently I'm using Arduino. The application stores some data in the Microcontroler (3 to 4 ko).

I'm thinking about replacing Arduino by Raspberry Pi and I would like to know please whether is possible to store some data in Raspberry Pi without an external memory (no usb flash, no hard drive).

Thanks

Comment: I am assuming you are using the eeprom on the arduino to store your data. The Pi does not have an eeprom. However, since it is a full Linux system that runs from the SD card you can write to the filesystem and store your data in a file on the SD card.

Answer (score 3):

The Raspberry Pi REQUIRES that you use a microSD card, and it loads software from the card as it boots up.  Most people keep Linux on the card, and any extra free space on the card can be used to store any data that you like.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike many Atmel chips (used in Arduinos) the Pi has no accessible internal flash memory.

You will need to store configuration data on the SD card.